# Image files with text on them: accessibility for visually impaired?

Tags: accessibility

I have a site with a number of written documents that are rendered as images. If I wanted to make them accessible to visually impaired people, it would seem that I would need to add the text somewhere.

Each document is rendered as a series of images, one for each page (see [this](https://robertrodes.com/work-samples/#EUW), for example). Would I want to each page's text into its corresponding image's `alt` attribute, or is there a better way to do it? And, if the `alt` attribute is the way to go, can I put the entire document in the image for the first page, or is it best to have the text in each attribute correspond exactly to the image it's in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most screenreader software won’t announce an entire page’s worth of content from an alt attribute, let alone a whole document. They have different cutoff points, but alts are intended to give short (a sentence or two) descriptions of pictures rather than large quantities of paragraphs, headings, tables, etc. You can test with a free screenreader (VoiceOver for Apple devices, or NVDA for Windows) to confirm this for yourself.

A better option would be to extract the text using OCR and put it into HTML or a Word doc that uses templated styles. That way people who can’t see the text can still have it read out plus they’ll be able to use all the usual navigation shortcuts like tables of contents and headings. You can still put any charts or graphs in as images with alts, and the amount of text you’d need to describe those would be much shorter and easier to write.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't need to extract the text. The originals are all in doc format. I exported to image files because I didn't like the way embedded pdf's behaved. So, probably HTML. Now, can you tell me if screen readers will read text that isn't displayed on the screen?

Comment: Yes, if the text is in the HTML but is visually hidden by CSS, screenreaders will still announce it. This can be useful if you need additional detail or context for people who can’t see the page.

Comment: Let me just be entirely clear on this, if I may. I can add all the text in HTML in a div, set the div's display to none, and screenreaders will still read it and bots will still crawl it?

Comment: Ah, good thing you clarified: setting it to {display: none} will remove it from the DOM so no-one at all will get it. Setting it to visibility:hidden, or using another CSS visually-hidden style, will hide it from sight but still leave it in the DOM so screenreader users can get it. This post explains your options: https://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/

Comment: Thanks for this. I was concerned about visibility:hidden creating a massive whitespace on the page, and your link has sorted that out for me. I didn't know about the clip thing; that looks like it will do the job for me.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the `alt` attribute as it is used for short descriptions only.

Making all this text accessible would mean rendering it in HTML. In your document, there are lists, there are tables, there are definition lists ; all this needs to be semantically described via HTML so that it is accessible. You would not be able to do this via the `alt` attribute.

I think of multiple ways you could make this accessible:

- have empty `alt` on all `img` and render all the text in HTML below the last image. The text can be visible to all, or only to those with screen readers as you wish (via the use of specific CSS, see the "sr-only" class of Bootstrap for example). If you want the text to be visible to all without taking too much visual space, you could hide it behind a toggle button (with the `aria-controls` and `aria-expanded` attributes).
- on each `img`, have a short `alt` attribute and a `longdesc` attribute. The `alt` is the title of current page, like "Table of Contents". The `longdesc` is a link to an HTML page having all the text on the image.
- after each `img`, have some HTML with the text of the image. This description can be visible to screen readers users only. Link each description via the `aria-describedby` attribute on the image.

I'd go with the first solution, because it's generally the simplest to deal with, and it benefits all users.

Comment: Thanks for your input.